# How to save many objects in the same request using Spring Boot Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm try save a array of an Entity using POST method passing an array for rest resource, but I have an error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of br.com.servtech.almox.model.Item out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@2af1e451; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of br.com.servtech.almox.model.Item out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@2af1e451; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

When's I send one object the data, the data is saved very well!

---

My Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private Integer quantity;

    @Basic
    private Double cash;

    @ManyToOne
    private Requirement requirement;

    //getters and setters
}
```

My Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin
public interface ItemDAO extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {

}
```

The Data:

```
[{ 
    "name": "A1", 
    "quantity": 3, 
    "cash": 5.80
}, { 
    "name": "B2", 
    "quantity": 3, 
    "cash": 5.80
}]
```

I've tried to using the Content-Type application/json and using with text/uri-list.
What is wrong? I do some more setup?

Comment: Please also post your controller method and the associated value object that comes with the request call..

Comment: He is using Spring Data Rest, he has already done that.

Comment: I've requested the feature, please vote:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong is that is trying to read your request body as an `Item`, when it is in fact multiple `Items`.

I believe you have two choices here. What I would normally do in this situation would be to create another resource, such as `ItemCollection`, to wrap multiple `Items`. Then you could have standard REST functionality to take in an `ItemCollection`, which would essentially handle multiple `Items`.

Your second option would be to manually override a method to handle multiple itmes: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up following your suggestion of the documentation. I leave here the link of the test repository that I made => https://github.com/rafaeldev/spring-boot-tests